# EF code first related entities not loading at all

Tags: entity-framework, mapping, foreign-keys, ef-code-first

I haven't been able to find someone else with this issue specifically so here goes.

I have a simple model where one entity simply references another as a parent-child or one-to-many relationship defined like this:

```
public class Parent
{
    public int ID { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }
}

public class Child
{
    public int ID { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public virtual Parent Parent { get; private set; }
}
```

I am creating speicific mapping files for each, which work great for all the normal properties except for the related entity. It is always coming up null. No matter whether i have the virtual/private accessors on the property it will not load UNLESS i pull a copy of the parent separately from the context first. My mapping looks like this:

```
HasRequired(t => t.Parent).WithMany().Map(t => t.MapKey("ParentID")).WillCascadeOnDelete();
```

Is there anything I am doing wrong with this? I cannot for the life of me figure this out. Just so I cover all the bases, I am loading the entity like this:

```
Context.Set<Child>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == 1);
```

And lastly here are some constraints I have:

1. I cannot have the foreign keys in my model as properties.
2. I cannot have a collection of children from the parent.

Comment: Works for me. The child is loaded by your query and child.Parent is loaded lazily the first time it is accessed.

Comment: Why do you have two classes to represent the child and the parent. Because they have same properties

Comment: @Jayantha maybe this is just example code...

Answer (score 4):

I finally figured it out. After much trial and error I noticed that having a parameterless constructor marked as internal, EF cannot create its dynamic proxy class of your type and therefore disables all lazy loading. I have two contructors, one for EF to hydrate objects, and another with parameters requires for callers to create my entity. Once I changed the signature to protected internal it started working. So I changed this:

```
internal Child() {}
```

to

```
protected internal Child() {}
```

Comment: Then you have put a different code here :). Plz update your question.

Comment: Seriously ... posting real code is the key to getting an answer, many reading this question would have spotted that instantly and given you an answer had you included it in the question.

Answer (score 0):

May be you hasn't enable lazy loading .Try this,

```
Context.Set<Child>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == 1).Include(c=>c.Parent);
```

Comment: That seemed to have worked, but I cant figure out why lazy loading is not enabled at all. I took off the virtual part of the property and even made sure I specified it as enabled in the context like this: Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;

Comment: To enable lazy loading, you need to have virtual properties and need to enable proxy creation.

Comment: did that but it didnt work. It turned out to be the parameterless constructor, see my answer above.